# how do i add hibernate-core to maven dependency library? no search result is showing when i search "hibernate" in Add Dependency window

Tags: hibernate, maven, search, dependencies

since there is no search result cannot add the hibernate library.
I have tried to input the artifact name and group id as i seen on a tutorial, Still then no result found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hibernate-core dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Make sure you change the version to the one you are using, or if you have a bom that includes hibernate, then remove the version element.

Comment: how to add dependency automatically to pom.xml file? I have right clicked on my project>Maven>Add Dependency but when i search no result is found. I need to add hibernate-core files to "Maven Dependency" Library.